# How can i run a Groovy script in Jenkins without getting java errors?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I try to run the following Groovy script in Jenkins Job.

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.* 
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
def jenkinsCredentials = 
 com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class,
    Jenkins.instance,
    null,
    null
);
```

But getting the error:

```
  The system cannot find the file specified
  FATAL: command execution failed
  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "groovy" (in directory 
   "E:\Jenkins\workspace\TestJob"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the 
    file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
.....
Build step 'Execute Groovy script' marked build as failure
```

Any ideas as to how i can fix this ?

Comment: I have tried to use System Groovy by select Add Job Task and just selecting Groovy Script and leaving as Default . Is there an example i can follow on what you mentioned ?

Comment: Made it an answer, so you can delete comments, accept and upvote answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you are running a Groovy script via a groovy plugin step. I believe you need to be using System Groovy in order to access the Jenkins internals (like `Jenkins.instance`).

There's a difference between "Execute System Groovy script" step and "Execute Groovy script" step. Pick the first. See the [Docs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy/#plugin-content-usage).